# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'db' before initialization

Tags: database, initialization

Getting an error cannot access 'db' before initialization. Not sure what is wrong here.
db is defined and imports from firebase.js to posts.js

Please help.

----firebase.js----

```
[// Initialize Firebase
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();
const storage [enter image description here][1]= getStorage();

export { app, db, storage };][1]
```

----posts.js----

```
import Post from "./Post";
import { collection, onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";



function Posts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubcribe = onSnapshot(
      query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")),
      (snapshot) => {
        setPosts(snapshot.docs);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      unsubcribe();
    };
  }, [db]);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          id={post.id}
          username={post.data().username}
          userImg={post.data().profileImg}
          img={post.data().image}
          caption={post.data().caption}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: return () => {
      unsubcribe();
    };
  }, [db]);

Comment: please look at those lines and see if it correct